# take a MKMapSnapShot of certain coordinates

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, snapshot

How can I take a map snapshot of certain coordinates? Right now it takes a snapshot of the whole map, but I want to only take a snapshot of NewYork( 40.7127° N, 74.0059°). I tried changing region.center to the New York coordinates, but I keep getting San Francisco.

```
MKMapSnapshotOptions *options = [[MKMapSnapshotOptions alloc] init];
options.region = self.mapView.region;
options.scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
options.size = self.mapView.frame.size;

MKMapSnapshotter *snapshotter = [[MKMapSnapshotter alloc] initWithOptions:options];
[snapshotter startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKMapSnapshot *snapshot, NSError *error) {
UIImage *image = snapshot.image;
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[data writeToFile:[self snapshotFilename] atomically:YES];
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it before. Here is a method to take a snap shot. Method required `CLLocationCoordinate2D` parameter, which in your case a location co-ordinates.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D centerPoint = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.730872, -74.003066);
```

Pass this co-ordinates in below method it will take snap of specified location. You can remove animation from this method if you want, It is nothing to do with functionality but it is good to show animate map to specific location. Have a look on this and share your thoughts.

```
- (void) takeSnapShot:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)centerPoint {

    __block MKCoordinateRegion newRegion = self.mapView.region;

    // Animation is use to animate map to location specified in parameter. If not required remove it.
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{

        MKCoordinateRegion region;
        region.center.latitude = centerPoint.latitude;
        region.center.longitude = centerPoint.longitude;
        region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.15f;
        region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.15f;
        newRegion = region;

        [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *fileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Snap.png"];

        MKMapSnapshotOptions *options = [[MKMapSnapshotOptions alloc] init];
        options.region = newRegion;
        options.scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
        options.size = self.mapView.frame.size;

        MKMapSnapshotter *snapshotter = [[MKMapSnapshotter alloc] initWithOptions:options];
        [snapshotter startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKMapSnapshot *snapshot, NSError *error) {
            UIImage *image = snapshot.image;
            NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
            [data writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES];
        }];

    }];
}
```